How to rebalance data across nodes?
I am implementing a message queue where messages are distributed across nodes in a cluster. The goal is to design a system to be able to auto-scale without needing to keep a global map of each message and its location.
My question is: when I add a new node, I want to rebalance messages. How do I handle requests that come in after the node has been added, but before data has been copied? This problem seems to exist regardless of the hashing algorithm I use.
Take this sequence of events:

There is a single node, A, with two messages, M1 and M2
Add new node, B. M2 should be moved to B.
The user attempts to delete M2. However, this fails because message is not yet found in B.

Ideally, I would route the request to node A while B is still being populated. But then B would have a stale state of data was modified.
How can I solve this problem of hot-swapping data between nodes without going as far as keeping a centralized database of all messages?

Which kind of message queue are you using? For example, RabbitMQ allows for clustering. Is that similar to what you need?

And by "implementing a message queue" do you mean you are choosing from an existing solution, or are you literally writing the code which will serve as a message queue?

In Kafka, changing the number of partitions only affects future messages. Existing messages remain in their partition and aren't moved around. However, brokers (nodes) in a cluster can fetch data from each other. So a client only has to connect to any node in the cluster, not to the node that happens to store the data. Perhaps you could implement a similar mechanism to internally route message reads to the correct node. But Kafka also makes some decisions (messages are immutable, clients pull messages) that make this feasible.

I am implementing my own queue from scratch, with the semantics of SQS.

The goal is for the system to automatically be able to scale up and down depending on load. I assume that rebalancing data is necessary here to be able to scale in without waiting for a single node to have 0 messages.

If this is a cloud-first design then storage will be virtualized anyway. You may be able to share storage, or reassign volumes to another compute node with little or no downtime. Actually moving data between nodes would make scaling down more difficult. However, your main problem isn't storing/moving data, but designing a distributed system. Your problems are shared with other databases that support sharding and/or replicas. Solutions will depend on your CAP priorities/ desired consistency model. Aside from "B doesn't have the data yet", also consider "B has crashed/frozen".

The system that you are describing seems like a "push" system to me. There is some LB that would assign (push) message to nodes for processing.
What about a "pull" system instead? Each individual node can autonomously pull messages from the MQ when it is available (you can define availability here). This ensures busy nodes are not overloading itself and free nodes are never free for long (barring absence of messages). New nodes added can process messages straight away.
In the example you gave above, all you have to do is publish another message signalling the deletion of M2. Whichever node has M2 can subscribe to that message, no hot swapping or need to keep track of messages in a database.
